# Dynamically get the count of partial no. of fields iterating through list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data file which has unit prices 1 to 4 along with other fields. For some of the rows all four unit prices are given and for some few of the unit prices are empty. I tried calculating the average unit price for each row by replacing space with zero but when I am doing the average I would like to ignore the unit price with space and divide it by the remaining count of items.

**Input:-**

```
10 20 30 40
30    50 60
20    10
```

**Code :-**

```
round(sum( float(v) if v else 0.0 for v in i[2:6])/4,2)
```

Output :-

```
25
46.66
15
```

Is there a way to get the count of values with in the list by ignoring spaces? Any inputs would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is `i` an iterable that contains the number in each column as a string, with empty columns represented as spaces?

Comment: i is  a list and inputm is a list of lists.... I am iterating through inputm and for each i I am doing some computation... In my case i is a single record and inputm is 'n' no. of records...

Comment: so, you have a working solution. Are you trying to find a "shorter" way?

Comment: No, I am dividing it by 4 now which is wrong... there is a chance that spaces can exist and if spaces are there I want to ignore them and do the mean for remaining unit prices.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the empty entries and calculate the mean using Python's standard `statistics` library.

```
import statistics

round(statistics.mean(float(x) for x in i[2:6] if x), 2)
```

Comment: was the output wrong or did you get an error? if you got an error, what was it?

Comment: ValueError: Could not convert string to float:

Comment: I am assuming that `i` contains `[..., '20', '  ', '10', '  ', ...]` for the third row of your input data. Is that incorrect?

Comment: i[2:6] can contain  [20, 30, 40, 50]  or [10,20,'',30]

Comment: so empty entries are represented by the empty string? try my modified code

Comment: the problem is with converting string to float not with isspace() function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140003/discussion-between-iafisher-and-teja).